# add result of image.plot layer on geographic map (bing map)

Tags: maps, field, raster, footprint

I have a 2D footprint result for an eddy-covariance system on a 1100*1100 square meter, with the domain of

```
    domain = c(-100,1000,-100, 1000)
```

the cell size of the domain (each grid) is 2 meters with the origin (0,0) accordingly on this location:

```
    Lon = -97.191391  #longtitude
    Lat = 36.055935   #latitude
```

An example data (9.01 Mb) is attached here. [FFP.rds](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t66zowytosdr0a6/FFP.rds?dl=0)

then I can plot a Bing map on my site as this:

```
   library(OpenStreetMap)
   library(rgdal)              
   map <- openmap(c(36.05778,-97.19250), c(36.05444,-97.18861),type='bing')
   plot(map)
```

and I use image.plot() from package "fields" to plot the footprint with these following codes:

```
  library(fields)
  str(FFP$fclim_2d)
  image.plot(FFP$x_2d[1,],FFP$y_2d[,1],FFP$fclim_2d)
```

But I am wondering how to scale each grid of my footprint result to Bing map (or google map).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: the key issue here is how to add latitude and longitude information for this regular grid (1100*1100 m^2 with 2 meter in resolution).

Comment: Finally, i use the extent function in sp packaged to geo-reference the footprint matrix as raster and save it as geo.tiff layer, and save the climatology lines as vector and save it as sptial_lines_data_frame and shapefiles. Then I use the tool "spatial adjustment" in arcmap to overlay the lines and raster.