# overlay flux footprint over a map

Tags: r, maps, gis, overlay, contour

I need to overlay a plot over a map (it can be from ggmap or from a file in my pc - not a shapefile).

```
    ### Here is the map
    library(ggmap)
    library(RgoogleMaps)

    lat = 49.12978
    lon = -122.985
    center = c(lat, lon)
    bbmap <- get_map(location = c(lon, lat), zoom = 18, maptype = "satellite")
```

And [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jTKYui8Q-oM0CxnDAT9Jv3JJnp8xrUb4)! is the data and the code to make the plot that I want to overlay.

```
    library(fields)
    image.plot(FFP$x_2d[1,],FFP$y_2d[,1],FFP$fclim_2d)
```

The main problem is that the plot uses distance to a point to generate a flux density plot, so there are no coordinates (I only have the center coordinates which I used to get the map)

This question is pretty much [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478211/add-result-of-image-plot-layer-on-geographic-map-bing-map)!  that hasn't been answered, but it seems that the solution is georeferencing the data. However, I don't know how to do that in R. I have tried using the "raster" function to create a 3D raster of the map and the image, using the extent of the map for both, but the plot seems not right because it looks like its rotated.

Ultimately, what I want is to have only the 90% or 80% contour line over the map, not the whole thing.

The final image should look something like [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dgAjd5VGs5klFB9gWA6LF8sEHa0ttKqf) but showing only the most external line, reference image: from [this](http://footprint.kljun.net/) webpage

Hope someone can help!

Thanks!